# Bash: How to retrieve a variable value inside a background while loop

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

As an example consider the following bash script. There are two loops, the first one executes in background and the second one prints `myvar` values:

```
#!/bin/bash

myvar=AAA

while true;
do
    sleep 3
    myvar=BBB
    sleep 3
    myvar=CCC
done &

while true;
do
    echo "${myvar}"
    sleep 1
done
```

The output I actually get:

```
AAA
AAA
AAA
...
```

The output I would like to get:

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
BBB
CCC
...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is due to the `&` creating a new subshell for the first while loop.

I'm pretty certain you'll need to use some kind of IPC to solve this. Using a pipe or a named pipe to implement a producer/consumer setup would be reasonable.

A rough example:

```
#!/bin/bash

myvar=AAA

while true;
do
    sleep 3
    myvar_piped=BBB
    echo $myvar_piped # this goes to the pipe.
    sleep 1
done | # this connects the two loops.

while true;
do
    # if we consumed something (timeout=1) print it, else print our own variable.
    if read -t 1 myvar_piped #
    then
        echo "${myvar_piped}"
    else
        echo "${myvar}"
    fi  
done
```

Outputs:

```
AAA
AAA
AAA
BBB
AAA
AAA
AAA
AAA
BBB
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm a bash newbie, can you give me any examples?

Comment: +1 for the example, however the first loop doesn't execute in background anymore, the two loops are sequential now, aren't they?

Comment: @Lorenzo: no, the pipe connects the first loop to the second and both execute in parallel barring the synchronization you can perform waiting for input and such. Think of it as any other pipe you may construct in the commandline, but with while loops instead of commands.

Comment: @Lorenzo: to clarify: in general when you use a pipe to filter text (think `ps auxww | grep root`) it is not true that the whole output of the first command is produced before being passed to the second command in the pipeline. Buffering may happen, but all the commands are running concurrently as if they were childs of different shells (they actually belong to the same process group in most Unix implementations, which may have an effect on scheduling I think, but that's a whole different subject).

Answer (score 5):

Substantially, there is nothing you can do to read the variable directly in the parent shell.

The first loop is run in a sub-shell because of the `&`; the sub-shell's memory is completely independent of the main shell's memory, and there's no way (short of doing ghastly things like running the debugger on the sub-shell) to access the child's memory from the parent shell.

If you can modify the sub-shell process to write its variable's value every second, then the parent might be able to detect that.  Alternatively, if the sub-shell writes the variable to a file with a known name every time it changes the variable, then you can read the file as often as you want in the parent:

```
#!/bin/bash

tmp=$(mktemp)

trap "rm -f $tmp; exit 1" 0 1 2 3 13 15

myvar=AAA
echo $myvar > $tmp

while true;
do
    sleep 3
    myvar=BBB
    echo $myvar > $tmp
    sleep 3
    myvar=CCC
    echo $myvar > $tmp
done &

while cat $tmp
do
    sleep 1
done

rm -f $tmp
trap 0
```

The trappery ensures the temporary file is removed under most circumstances (signals HUP, INT, QUIT, PIPE and TERM).

Comment: Thanks. Do you think a more powerful scripting language will fit better my needs?

Comment: Having to set up shared memory in any scripting language does not appeal at all - even though I expect Perl and Python could do the job.  You'd still have to arrange for them to write to and read from the shared memory, so you'd have to be able to locate the variable in the shared memory.  I think some sort of file-based IPC system might be better for you.  A more powerful scripting language would be able to keep the file open in the parent and rewind and reread, rather than reopening the file every second.  OTOH, when you've got a `sleep 1` in the loop, performance ain't that critical.